# Select max common Date from differents DataFrames (Scala Spark)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have differents dataframes and **I want to select the max common Date of these DF**. For example, I have the following dataframes:

```
+--------------+-------+
|Date          | value |
+--------------+-------+
|2015-12-14    |5      |
|2017-11-19    |1      |
|2016-09-02    |1      |
|2015-12-14    |3      |
|2015-12-14    |1      |

+--------------+-------+
|Date          | value |
+--------------+-------+
|2015-12-14    |5      |
|2017-11-19    |1      |
|2016-09-02    |1      |
|2015-12-14    |3      |
|2015-12-14    |1      |

+--------------+-------+
|Date          | value |
+--------------+-------+
|2015-12-14    |5      |
|2012-12-21    |1      |
|2016-09-02    |1      |
|2015-12-14    |3      |
|2015-12-14    |1      |
```

The selected date would be **2016-09-02** because is the max date that exists in these 3 DF (*the date 2017-11-19 is not in the third DF*).

I am trying to do it with `agg(max)` but in this way I just have the highest date of a DataFrame:

```
df1.select("Date").groupBy("Date").agg(max("Date))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do semi joins to get the common dates, and aggregate the maximum date. No need to group by date because you want to get its maximum.

```
val result = df1.join(df2, Seq("Date"), "left_semi").join(df3, Seq("Date"), "left_semi").agg(max("Date"))
```

You can also use `intersect`:

```
val result = df1.select("Date").intersect(df2.select("Date")).intersect(df3.select("Date")).agg(max("Date"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't test it because I need to change some values in my Parquet file. How can I change a specific value for example of the row 5?

Comment: There is no such thing as "row 5". Parquet files are unordered.

Comment: And it is posible to do this and mantein just one column of the second DF? (for example select the column Value, is not in the table of the topic but suposse that exists) asking you to not open another thread. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can do `.agg(max(struct("Date","value")))` at the end